# как написать матрицу с генерацией случайных чисел?

Tags: php

задача следующая: написать матрицу 4х4 с выводом случайных чисел от 0 до 100? как это реализовать?

Код:

```
var_dump(getRandomNumbers(1, 100, 4)); 
function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $count)
{
    if ($count > (($max - $min)+1)) { return false; }
    $values = range($min, $max); 
    shuffle($values);
    return array_slice($values,0, $count); 
}
```

Comment: А что у вас не получилось? Можете показать, что вы хотели сделать, но не получилось?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
`var_dump(getRandomNumbers(1, 100, 4));

 function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $count)
 {
    if ($count > (($max - $min)+1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $values = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($values);
    return array_slice($values,0, $count);
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще:

```
function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $count)
{
    $array=array();
    for($i=0;$i<$count;++$i){
        for($j=0;$j<$count;++$j){
            $array[$i][$j]=rand($min,$max);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

var_dump(getRandomNumbers(0, 100, 4));
```